# EWS 2010 Get Calendar items without using Impersonation C#

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I have a crawler that used to use an impersonation account to crawl users calendars.
Now, I can not use this impersonation account and need to find a way for the crawler to work.

Is there a way to access user's calendars without using the impersonation account?
If there is a way, would you please explain how to do it and what do I need to do to make it work?

Also, would you point me to a sample code if there is one as a reference?

Thank you,
Rad1

Answer (score 2):

Actually, those users could grant you a [Delegate access](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2009/06/15/exchange-impersonation-vs-delegate-access.aspx) to their mailboxes.

After that, access their folders from `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data` code like this:

```
rootfolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, 
  new Mailbox(delegateEmail));
```

Answer (score 0):

well the only way other than impersonation is to know the passwords of each user, which is not practical solution.

Comment: Nope, there's also a delegation access.